# Mac mail application that can import older Apple Mail "MBOX" files?

Tags: macos, mac, email, mbox

I've got some old MBOX files from an older version of Apple Mail and I want to convert them into something more modern.

The only thing I've found that has handled these so far is Airmail, but this unfortunately rendered some additional PLIST XML data into the mail body:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"  "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
```

... This is a little sloppy in my opinion, but unfortunately Airmail is the only client that I've been able to find that will actually handle these files. Thunderbird wouldn't, and aside from booting an older version of OS X (perhaps unsuccessfully) in a VM, I'm kind of at a loss as to what else to try.

Has anyone else had luck importing these PLIST-augmented MBOX files with anything?

Comment: Version numbers, OS, Mail, Airmail… might help...

Comment: I don't have them, ha. Airmail is 1.4.2 (latest before they forced everyone to pay again, so I stopped using it). — My guess is that Mail was from OS X 10.7? But maybe earlier